# SQL - Sum of Same Column With Different Criteria - One Distinct, One Not

Tags: sql

I have an issue I can't figure out at the moment. I am trying to figure out how to sum data from the same column but with a condition on one of the 'sums'.

I am dealing with events that have hours. One event type, F2F, doesn't have to be distinct. I would like to add F2F with Groups, which have to be unique by group Id. Other wise a group that was an hour long with 5 people would be 5 hours instead of one.

So I need sum(F2Fhours) + sum(hours by distinct group_id)

The F2F don't have a group id but are on the same table so if I try to GROUP BY group_id it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post input Table with sample data and expected output.

Comment: which sql version?